# In Spring Boot 2, using the RestTemplate, how do I set a default read timeout?

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, default, resttemplate

I'm using Spring Boot 2.  I have

```
@Value("${my.read.timeout:-1}")
private Integer timeout;

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRt() {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(getFactory());
    return rt;
}

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    return factory;
}
```

The problem is "-1" is not a valid default value for the timeout setting.  If no explicit property is defined I would like to use whatever the default read timeout is.  How do I do this?

Comment: if (timeout == null || timeout == -1) {
            factory.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT); 
        } else {
            factory.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        }

Comment: I might go this way, the inconvenience with this is, to satisfy test coverage, I have to write multiple tests for each situation (timeout == null, timeout != null, tineout == -1, timeout != -1), whereas if I have a single expression in the @Value clause, I only need to have one unit test to satisfy coverage.